# Cannot understand how this Func<in T, out T> should work with Url.Action delegate

Tags: c#, razor, html-helper, asp.net-mvc-5

```
@Html.PageLinks(Model.PagingInfo, x => Url.Action("List", new { page = x }))
```

I have this in my view and I want to add 2 more properties (so I added some more arguments to the Func delegate...):

```
@Html.PageLinks(Model.PagingInfo, x => Url.Action("List",
    new { page = x, 
          sort = Request.QueryString["sort"], 
          desc = Request.QueryString["desc"] }))
```

but when I add 2 more properties it doesn't work... what am I not understanding here?

And I have the following html helper:

```
public static MvcHtmlString PageLinks(this HtmlHelper html,
    PagingInfo pagingInfo, Func<int, string, string, string> pageUrl)
{
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 1; i <= pagingInfo.TotalPages; i++)
    {
        TagBuilder liTag = new TagBuilder("li"); 
        TagBuilder aTag = new TagBuilder("a"); 

        aTag.MergeAttribute("href", pageUrl(i, 
           pagingInfo.Sort, pagingInfo.Desc.ToString())); // pageUrl delegate is here helloooo
        aTag.InnerHtml = i.ToString();
        if (i == pagingInfo.CurrentPage)
            liTag.AddCssClass("active");

        liTag.InnerHtml = aTag.ToString();

        result.Append(liTag.ToString());
    }
    return MvcHtmlString.Create(result.ToString());
}
```

P.S my controller looks like this:

```
public ViewResult List(int page = 1, string sort = "Name", bool desc = false)
{...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The

```
x => Url.Action("List",
   new { page = x, 
      sort = Request.QueryString["sort"], 
      desc = Request.QueryString["desc"] })
```

is still a lambda expression that denotes a method that expects **one** parameter. The fact that in the method body you create an anonymous object with three properties is irrelevant.

You want to change it to

```
(x, y, z) => Url.Action("List",
   new { page = x, 
      sort = y, 
      desc = z }))
```

This way when you invoke it as

```
pageUrl(i, pagingInfo.Sort, pagingInfo.Desc.ToString())
```

all three ( `i`, `pagingInfo.Sort` and `paginginInfo.Desc.ToString()`) will be captured by consecutive parameters (`x`, `y` and `z`). I would even recommend renaming for clarity:

```
(pageNumber, sortOrder, descending) => Url.Action("List",
   new { page = pageNumber, sort = sortOrder, desc = descending }))
```

Comment: Oh my god, you're a genius. that's awesome man! Yehaaaa, smile 2 the maxage! how do I push the values through into delegate function? ie... Request.QueryString...

Comment: +1 This is good explanation, but consider having single argument like `PagingParameters option` - `Func<T1,T2,T3,TR>` unfortunately does not provide good documentation on what parameters mean, especially if most are of the same type.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: I've been updating my answer with the recommendation to rename parameters just as you posted your comment. Thanks anyway.